# Understanding Resolving Promises when Accessing REST Service with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm trying to get an asynchronous process to resolve in a synchronous web application widget I'm working on and I've been unable to have success (not for lack of effort!). I've also tried to implement some of the useful help from this [Understanding Promises in Javascript](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321490/understanding-promises-in-javascript)  but when I've made attempts to use the following:

```
_calculateSusMAI: function _calculateSusMAI(pointAttributes, _hpslFieldNames) {

  let susMAIFieldName = this.config.Layers.SusMAI.FieldNames.SusMAI;
  let susMAIUrl = this.config.Layers.SusMAI.Url
  let vegTypeFieldName = this.layers.cruisePointsLayer.FieldNames.VegType;
  let queryVegTypeFieldName = this.config.Layers.SusMAI.FieldNames.VegType;
  let soilTypeFieldName = this.layers.cruisePointsLayer.FieldNames.SoilType;
  let querySoilTypeFieldName = this.config.Layers.SusMAI.FieldNames.SoilType;
  let ecoDistrict = _hpslFieldNames.ecodistrict;
  let queryEcoDistrictFieldName = this.config.Layers.SusMAI.FieldNames.EcoDistrict;
  sumSusMAIResult = 0
  whereArray = []

  async function _querySusMAI(queryVegTypeFieldName,vegType,querySoilTypeFieldName,soilType,queryEcoDistrictFieldName,ecoDistrict,susMAIFieldName, susMAIUrl) {
    susMAIArray = []
    var queryTask = new QueryTask(susMAIUrl);
    var query = new Query();
    query.where = queryVegTypeFieldName + "='" + vegType + "' AND " + querySoilTypeFieldName + "='" + soilType + "' AND " + queryEcoDistrictFieldName + "='" + ecoDistrict  +"'";
    query.outFields = [susMAIFieldName];
    query.returnGeometry = false;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      queryTask.execute(query).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        let features = result.features[0].attributes.susmai;
        susMAIArray.push(features)
        console.log(susMAIArray)
        })
        resolve("initResolve");
      });
    }
  

  for (var i = 0; i < pointAttributes.length; ++i) {
    vegType = pointAttributes[i][vegTypeFieldName];
    soilType = pointAttributes[i][soilTypeFieldName];

    async function work() {
      let susMAIResult = _querySusMAI(queryVegTypeFieldName,vegType,querySoilTypeFieldName,soilType,queryEcoDistrictFieldName,ecoDistrict,susMAIFieldName, susMAIUrl);
    console.log(susMAIResult)
    }

    work()
}},
```

Well, much closer than I was before. This initially returns a pending promise, then, when my synchronous code is complete, it returns fulfilled and provides results. I just need to figure out how to get await to work but have so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: I am not completely familiar with what you're attempting but from a quick search I think that the problem is that the main function or high-level function is not set to async - you need to set the function _calculateSusMAI(pointAttributes, _hpslFieldNames) to async, from what I read. So something like async function _calculateSusMAI(pointAttributes, _hpslFieldNames) { Hope this helps.